# How to submit on web page to download file using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've looked at quite a few suggestions for clicking on buttons on web pages using python, but don't fully understand what the examples are doing and can't get them to work (particularly the ordering and combination of values).

I'm trying to download a PDF from a web site. 
The first time you click on the PDF to download it, it takes you to a page where you have to click on "Agree and Proceed". Once you do that the browser stores the cookie (so you never need to agree again) and then opens the PDF in the browser (which is what I want to download).

Here is the link to the accept page - https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/displayAnnouncement.do?display=pdf&idsId=02232753"

I've used Chrome Developer to get this:-

`<form name="showAnnouncementPDFForm" method="post" action="announcementTerms.do">
    <input value="Decline" onclick="window.close();return false;" type="submit">
    <input value="Agree and proceed" type="submit">
    <input name="pdfURL" value="/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf" type="hidden">
</form>`

and this is the final page you get to:- "https://www.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf"

then tried to use it like this:-

```
import requests
values = {}
values['showAnnouncementRDFForm'] = 'announcementTerms.do'
values['pdfURL'] = '/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf'
req = requests.post('https://asx.com.au/', data=values)
print(req.text)
```

I tried a variety of URL's and changed what values I provide, but I don't think it's working correctly.
The print at the end provides me with what looks like the HTML form a web page. I'm not sure exactly what it is as I'm doing this from the command line of a server I'm ssh'd into (Pi). But I'm confident it's not the PDF I'm after.

As a final solution I'd like the python code to do is take the PDF link, automatically Agree and Proceed, store the cookie for next to to avoid future approvals, then download the PDF.

Hope that made sense and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to download the file directly and you know the URL you can access it without using a cookie:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf")
with open('./test1.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

If you don't know the URL you can read it from the form then access it directly without a cookie:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = "https://www.asx.com.au"
response = requests.get(f"{base_url}/asx/statistics/displayAnnouncement.do?display=pdf&idsId=02232753")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pdf_url = soup.find('input', {'name': 'pdfURL'}).get('value')
response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{pdf_url}')
with open('./test2.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

if you want to set the cookie:

```
import requests
cookies = {'companntc': 'tc'}
response = requests.get("https://www.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf", cookies=cookies)
with open('./test3.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

If you really want to use POST:

```
import requests   
payload = {'pdfURL': '/asxpdf/20200506/pdf/44hlvnb8k3n3f8.pdf'}
response = requests.post('https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/announcementTerms.do', params=payload)
with open('./test4.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Or read the pdfURL from the form and do a POST:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = "https://www.asx.com.au"
response = requests.get(f"{base_url}/asx/statistics/displayAnnouncement.do?display=pdf&idsId=02232753")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pdf_url = soup.find('input', {'name': 'pdfURL'}).get('value')
payload = {'pdfURL': pdf_url}
response = requests.post(f"{base_url}/asx/statistics/announcementTerms.do", params=payload)
with open('./test5.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Wow Dan-Dev awesome set of answers, thank you very much. I'm disappointed in myself for not thinking to extract the URL from the form and go directly there. I think I assumed it just wouldn't work without accepting. I also think I need to get a lot better understanding of ''requests', from your examples it seems it can do pretty much anything.